# arcpy.Delete_management does not delete the directory

Tags: arcpy, scratch-workspace

I got a problem with Delete_management when I use the *FeatureclassToCoverage_conversion* function. I don't know why in the gdb I use (arcpy.env.scratchGDB), while the Delete_management is working, the folder is not completely deleted : 2 lockers file stay in.

Here is the code I use (I reduced it to the minimum) :

```
import os
import arcpy

from os.path import join

# User entries on ArcGIS
out_cover = "C:\Users\user\coverage"
in_lines = "C:\Users\user\lines.shp"
in_points = "C:\Users\user\points.shp"

# Unsplit the lines
fusionned_lines = join(arcpy.env.scratchGDB, "fusionned_lines")
arcpy.UnsplitLine_management(in_lines, fusionned_lines)

# Copy the feature
points = join(arcpy.env.scratchGDB, "points")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_points, points)

# List the feature classes to put in the coverage.
points_and_lines = [points, fusionned_lines]

# Create the coverage directory if needed.
if not arcpy.Exists(out_cover):
    os.makedirs(out_cover)

# Convert the feature class list into a coverage.
arcpy.FeatureclassToCoverage_conversion(points_and_lines, out_cover)

# The Delete_management of fusionned_lines and points is comparlsary, otherwise
# it is impossible to delete the scratch workspace.
arcpy.Delete_management(fusionned_lines)
arcpy.Delete_management(points)
# This delete does not work like I want :
arcpy.Delete_management(arcpy.env.scratchGDB)
```

In the scratch.gdb folder I always have a locker for fusionned_lines and a locker for points. For the first treatment it doesn't matter, but because of that I can't execute the script more than once.

Moreover, if I don't add the line : *arcpy.FeatureclassToCoverage_conversion(points_and_lines, out_cover)*, the scratchGDB delete correctly. So the problem definitely come from here, but I don't know why or how.

Comment: Have you per chance set arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = *some gdb path*? You need to undo your scratch workspace before you delete it. Try oldScratch = arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace ..do your stuff.. delGDB = arcpy.env.scratchGDB / arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = oldScratch / arcpy.Delete_management(delGDB) - that should remove the whole lot.

Comment: No this is the whole code I let the scratch in the tmp files.

Comment: If you're not creating the scratch database then leave it alone. ArcGis needs a scratch database to operate.. of course remove your feature classes as you see fit but don't delete the scratch GDB. You should only delete a database that your process has created.

Comment: So I have to delete each feature class I create in the scratch GDB and I don't delete the scratch... But does it changes anything at the end of my script, to delete the scratchGDB ?

Comment: An other question : is it better to use this GDB for intermediate treatments or to create a TEMP GDB I could remove myself ?

Comment: Generally I would create one myself, use os.environ.get("TEMP") to locate your temp directory and then create one.. if you want to see that done in a script I can put that in as an answer. However, on TEMP, it defaults to the user profile which can be a bad place for it - permissions, locking, quotas etc.. I *always* set my TEMP and TMP to another folder (it *can* be on the C drive, but I put it at the root level, like C:\WINtemp) where I know for sure I have access control as creator/owner.

Comment: ArcGIS Server geoprocessing creates an empty geodatabase as part of geoprocessing task initialization, and deletes the project folder as part of tear-down, so technically, you don't need to delete objects "on the clock" if this is part of a geoprocessing service (I often do, but only when it doesn't take a long time, e.g., more than 2-3 seconds).